# Custom main nib file can't connect actions to targets

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

On application launch, I receive the output: "Could not connect the action to target of class NSApplication" for each of the buttons I have created.

In my Info.plist file, I changed the Main nib file base name to MyWindowController.
In the corresponding MyWindowController.xib, my Application placeholder's class is NSApplication, and its delegate outlet is set to my main application delegate.
My File Owner placeholder's class is set to MyWindowController, and I have buttons set up to perform actions.
MyWindowController.xib is the only xib file in my project.

I'm not all that familiar with connections in xib files, and I'm not sure I understand the difference between an Application and a File Owner when there is only 1 xib file.
Basically, I just want the window I have created in MyWindowController.xib to appear upon app launch and for the outlets I have made with the File Owner to be connected to this window.

Any suggestions or ideas on how I should proceed?

Comment: Why didn't you use the `MainMenu.xib` supplied with the Xcode Template?

Comment: I could add it back to the project, but I'd like to figure out how to do it this way. I wanted to learn how to set up a custom xib as the only xib file.